# How assign the width of the longest element to other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following element

[image]

The exercise names are dynamic so the width of the button containing the exercise name will vary but the the accompanying color button is fixed width. The parent element has `width: auto; height: auto` to it will fit to however many buttons there are regardless of how long the exercise name is.

**How can I make the length all of the buttons equal to the width of the widest exercise name button?**

Or similarly, **how can I get these buttons to align but not overflow, even if longer exercise names are chosen.?**

Comment: Can you provide a complete workable example?

Comment: If the width of the right side of the buttons doesn't change, you can wrap the buttons in a container and then set the width of the left side to `calc(100% - 40px)` but change 40px to whatever the width of the right side is.

Comment: I'll try, I'm not very good on jfiddle yet, but I need to learn

Comment: Will a javascript / jquery solution work for you?

Comment: @APAD1 I think your comment should be an answer, that's cleaner than a javascript solution

Comment: set button width to 100% and that's it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for solution in CSS only, there's one way using the `display` property as `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell`. I think you can extend it for your markup:

```css
.btn-container {
  display: table;
  border: 1px #000 solid !important;
}
.btn {
  display: table-row;
}
.btn-text {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px;
}
.btn-label {
  width: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.btn-label-red {
    background: #F00;
}
.btn-label-green {
    background: #0F0;
}
.btn-label-blue {
    background: #00F;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">

  <div class="btn">
    <span class="btn-text">Button 1</span>
    <span class="btn-label btn-label-green"> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <span class="btn-text">Button 2 with large text</span>
    <span class="btn-label btn-label-red"> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <span class="btn-text">Btn 3</span>
    <span class="btn-label btn-label-blue"> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a maxwidth variable set to 0, then use a jquery selector to pull the buttons and for each of them check to see if the width is greater than the max, if it is update the maxwidth variable. Finally, after running through all of them use the same selector to set the width of all of the buttons.

Comment: Well I didn't think Javascript would be necessary, but I think I'll try to solve it this way

Comment: @APAD1 added, since it has become part of the solution

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I can't give you an exact answer, but there are a few ways to do this. The first way would be to use the [CSS calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to set the width of the left side of the button to 100% minus the width of the right side of the button:

```
.button-left {
    width:calc(100% - 40px); /* Change 40px to whatever the width of the right side is */
}
```

The other way, as @SumGuy mentioned would be to use jQuery to set the width of all elements to the largest width of all buttons. You can do that by looping through each element like this:

```
function equalWidth(element) {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    element.each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $(this).width());
    });
    group.css({ width: maxWidth + 'px' });
}
equalWidth($('.button')); //Change the selector to whatever your button class is.
```

If you set up a JSFiddle I can give you an exact answer that would apply to your specific HTML markup.

Comment: Wouldn't the CSS solution only work when the container's width is set to a fixed value?